Как решить задачу 82, acmp.ru
Вот условие задачи:
(Время: 1 сек. Память: 64 Мб)

Даны два неупорядоченных набора целых чисел (может быть, с повторениями). Выдать без повторений в порядке возрастания все те числа, которые встречаются в обоих наборах.
Входные данные


В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записано через пробел два целых числа N и М (1 ≤ N, М ≤ 300 000) — количество элементов первого и второго наборов, соответственно. Во второй строке записано N чисел первого набора через пробел. В третьей строке записано M чисел второго набора через пробел. Каждое из этих чисел попадает в промежуток от 0 до 105.
Выходные данные


В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT нужно записать в возрастающем порядке без повторений все числа, которые входят как в первый, так и во второй набор. Числа разделять одним пробелом. Если таких чисел нет, то выходной файл должен оставаться пустым.

Можно использовать потоки cin и cout
Уже попробовал несколько решений, такие как:
Типо "сортировка подсчётом"
Дальше с помощью set
И с помощью unordered_set
И наконец, с помощью сортировки
Все решения проваливаются или на десятом тесте, или на одинадцатом, с вердиктом:
Time limit exceeded
Соостветственно не хватает времени, может кто нибудь подскажет более скоростной способ?
Использую компилятор: MINGW GNU C++ 14.2.0
Самый быстрый код оказался:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
  
using namespace std;
  
int main()
{
    int n,m, t;
    scanf("%i",&n);
    scanf("%i",&m);
    vector<int> a;
    vector<int> b;
    vector<int> c(1000000);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        scanf("%i",&t);
        a.push_back(t);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
        scanf("%i",&t);
        b.push_back(t);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        c[a[i]] = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
        if(c[b[i]] == 1)
            c[b[i]] = 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < c.size(); ++i){
        if(c[i] == 2)
            printf("%i", i);
        printf(" ");
    }
    return 0;
}

1.25 секунд на 11 тесте

Как минимум векторы a и b можно сразу выкинуть - вы их всё равно используете только для наполнения c, который можно наполнять сразу после scanf

Ну приведите хоть какой-то код, а то формально ж вам помогать нельзя :) Обратите внимание, что числа небольшие. Ну? Намек понятен?

даже если их выкинуть, времени не хватает

Нет, намёк как то не понятен)

Ввод/вывод не ускорены.

Так намек понятен?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

unsigned char a[100001], b[100001];

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    int N, M;
    in >> N >> M;
    for(int d, i = 0; i < N; ++i) { in >> d; a[d] = 1; }
    for(int d, i = 0; i < M; ++i) { in >> d; b[d] = 1; }
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 100001; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] & b[i]) out << i << " ";
    }
}


Нет, не понятен, 1.156 на 10 тесте

У меня прошел и по времени, и по правильности :)

Какой у вас компилятор стоит?

Можно обойтись одним массивом, заполняя в нём разные биты для a и для b.

А, всё, реально прошло, хотя почему то показало TLE сначало, странно

Компилятор не важен, проверяет acmp своим компилятором.

Хитрость решения в отказе от стандартных потоков ввода/вывода, файлы быстрее читаются/пишутся. А потоки надо настраивать.

Там какая-то странная лажа. Я эту задачу когда-то уже решал; взял старое принятое решение, запустил по новой - не прошло по времени!...

А зачем размер массива 100001?  "Каждое из этих чисел попадает в промежуток от 0 до 105". Это массив из 106 байт. Нулевой бит ставим в 1 для первого набора, первый для второго. Выводим i для элемента равного 3

@avp Возни много, а я показывал идею. Плюс скорость там и так критична (см. мой комментарий выше).

@avp Это десять в пятой степени так часто копируют, не заметив, или не понимая смысла, или поленившись исправить

@MBo, тогда понятно
